# Behance-like content filter possible in drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

Asked the same question [here](http://drupal.org/node/1430610#comment-5569876) but got no answer, so I'm trying here instead :)

Hey,

I'm working on a site somewhat similar to [Behance](http://www.behance.net/).

To make you understand what I'm talking about, I'll explain a little bit;

I got a content type called say... "Content", which can go into three different categories, "Category 1", "Category 2" and "Category 3".

Then, I got a page called "Content filter" where I can see all the content in the different categories.

On this page I'm able to filter what should be shown by choosing category and time (time since uploaded content).

So if I choose Category 1 and 1 Month or something like that, it will filter the content on the page to what I choose, without uploading the page. So I would call it something like "Live content filter", I hope you get the idea.

Anyways,
I know how to make all this, but then it's not filtering without going to another page, and I have to make way too many views.

Hopefully someone can help me with this, would be really great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to set your View setting where it says, `Use AJAX: No` to "`Yes`". That way and exposed filters  / pagers will dynamically load the filtered content without doing a page reload or going to another page. You may have to experiment with using a "Block" display vs. a "Page" (URL path) display. You may also need to use *Views Arguments* as a way on cutting down on the number of Views you need to create.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful. I'll try it out tomorrow and be back with some results!

Comment: Worked great! Just got some problem with the time because I can't get all the different time options (all, day, week...) in the same list. Instead I have to make different filters for every option, and that's not really what I need.